# Find shortest list for constructing a number by summing integers of another list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, math

I have a list of integers:

```
S = [10, 100, 35, 50, 75, 200, 500]
```

I need to construct **1420** with summing list `S` elements and I need to find smartest (you read shortest) list.
In this case, I am looking for `[500,500,200,200,10,10]`

I search many resources and I couldn't find a way.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a classical dynamic programming problem called coin change problem. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

Comment: Yes, This question is a duplicate.  Thank you for your comments.  I am closing this thread.